# ORMLite display accents accents and other unicode symbols

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have seen in [ORMLite documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#IDX106)  that stored strings with unicode symbols you have to use `String (DataType.STRING_BYTES)`. But Have I to change the String attribute for a ArrayBytes too?

Until now I have used @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING_BYTES) above my String attribute, but this not work.

**Model**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="Messages")
public class Message {

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING_BYTES)
    private String message;

    //get and set methods...

...
}
```

**Activity**

```
...
    TextView message = new TextView(this);
    message.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    message.setText(m.getMessage());
    linearLayout.addView(message);
...
```

Comment: I can't quite parse the 2nd sentence in your post.  Can you edit and rewrite it?

Comment: How do you know that it is not working?   Can you show your input, the database bytes, and the output?

Comment: Because I saved in the database a text and then when I tried restore it, message appear with odd symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of Eclipse. This code run perfectly. 
For any reason sometimes, Eclipse  has replaced some symbols like accents and other special letters for odd symbols. And it was doing it when it was saving my source code.